# Create-React-App/React Router Not Working On Deployment via Render

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, react-router

Trying to deploy my first React application. The index route is visible but none of the relative endpoints work and I get a 404 from the render server. However I read that I needed to make these changes to the deployment in order for the client-side routing to work properly:

[Render's suggestion for configuring client-side routing to work properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZndfN.png)

However, when I visit an endpoint like `"/login"` or `"/signup"`, the react router in my app catches it as a 404 and
[renders the 404 page, and the endpoint in the url changes to /index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZYC.png)

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Views from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserProvider } from "./context/userContext.js";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <UserProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Views />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </UserProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PublicRoutes from "./routes/PublicRoutes";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { useUser } from "./context/userContext.js";

function Views() {
  const { loading } = useUser();

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<PublicRoutes />} />
      </Routes>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Views;
```

Routing Logic:

```
const PublicRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={new QueryClient()}>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="signup" element={<SignUpMUI />} />
        <Route element={<Protect />}>
          <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>} />
          <Route path="event/:id" element={<EventPage />} />
          <Route path="profile" element={<>Profile Page</>} />
          <Route path="settings" element={<>Settings</>} />
        </Route>    
        <Route path="*" element={<h1>404</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default PublicRoutes;
```

I thought maybe it has something to do with the file pathing because my repository contains a sub-folder for the API and then a sub-folder for the react application so maybe I thought I had to route the html pathing as /client/index.html or something but that didn't work. Honestly I have no idea what I am supposed to do, I have very little experience with deploying and with most resources and tutorials covering how to deploy with Heroku (which has recently deprecated their free tier) and most tutorials covering React deployment on Render don't involve any usage of the react router.

Also, I would like to reiterate the structure of the repository as it contains two sub folders, one which contains the react application called "client" and another which contains the server code called "server". Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8JI9.png)

I'm thinking maybe this has something to do with the redirections to the index.html but Idk, I've already tried messing about with the configuration on render to see if it would make a difference but no dice.

Comment: What is "Render" here in this context, a web hosting service? Where are you deploying the app to, Heroku? Each server/environment might require different configurations.

Comment: Render is a hosting service

https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app

Comment: I haven't used React Router for a long time, but are you sure your current setup works locally? Perhaps changing `path="login"` to path="/login"?

Comment: So you are hosting/deploying your app to Render. Is Heroku relevent here then? You've shared public routes, can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] that includes the router and root routes, and where this `PublicRoutes` component is rendered?

Comment: Yeah it works, the forward slash is optional in RR

Comment: @MatthewKwong That's ok, the routes are built relative to their parent `Routes` component, the leading `"/"` isn't required in all cases.

Comment: @DrewReese Sure, I will add more info to the post

Comment: Could you also confirm if your code is running as expected when running a local development build?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, it works perfectly fine in development

Comment: I see. And you are sure you set ***and saved*** the settings/configuration as specified in [using client-side routing](https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing)?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, following along with this guide here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-react-routing-in-production,

I attempted to restart my deployment and still no luck

Comment: Hmm, there's really not much to their docs, and if you really followed them, and the code is working normally locally, you might need to contact their support.

Comment: @DrewReese Do you think it has something to do with the structure of my repository? I added an image. Do you think that would impact how I path to the /index.html via the render configuration settings? Because when the repository can only build if I first tell render to prefix the build command with /client. I figured that logic woul apply here as well and maybe it would have to be /client/build/index.html but still got the 404

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Normally you are deploying a built artifact, e.g. something built and copied to a "build" directory and deployed, not a repo. It looks like Render accesses a repo though. Can you share a link to your repo if it's public for us to take a quick look?

Comment: @DrewReese sure! here ya go:

https://github.com/angelplusultra/evnt

Comment: This seems like it may be useful: https://community.render.com/t/how-to-deploy-frontend-and-backend-on-render/7449 and https://render.com/docs/monorepo-support

Answer (score 3):

Just read: https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app

and add this to **Redirects/Rewrites** section

[image]

Comment: Would be good to have a link to the documentation page instead of the screenshot

Comment: @Dmitriy, the first line of my message